# "Db/txn-current-lock permission denied" Error on Linux SVN Server

Tags: svn, webmin, svn-administraton

For source controlling, I installed **SVN** .After that Add **SVN Admin** add-on in **Webmin** to configure users and their permission visually.
But I got an error when commit a new file/folder to repository. It seems the problem comes from user permission in repository directory: **SVN** Admin make repository with 'csvn' user but **Apache** can't write in the repository folder.
I don't want to add 777 permission to repository or change the owner to **Apache**, because after any change in repository by **SVN Admin**, this problem returns.

Whats the best solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding group write permissions to the folder and adding the apache user to the csvn user's group should help with this: `chmod g+w /svn/repository` then `usermod -a -G csvn apache` (substituting the correct path, user and group names - it's group first then username in the usermod command). Hope that gets it working for you.

Comment: I have done this approach, It fix problem for current repository. But if I add new repository, I have to do " chmod g+w /svn/newRepository " for new repo.

Comment: That'll always be the case I think. If it's too much of a pain you could always set something up in cron that'll run that command every day/hour/whatever on the directory you store your repos in though?